# How to generate table in from select tag in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible (how) to change table depending on select tag?

Code in index.html.erb

```
<p><%= select_tag "Stocks", options_from_collection_for_select(@stocks, "id", "ticker") %></p>
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Market Price</th>           
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <% @stock.market_prices.order(:closing_date).reverse.each do |mp|%>
        <tr> 
          <td><%=mp.closing_date %></td>
          <td><%=number_with_precision(mp.closing_price, precision: 2) %></td>
        <%end%>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

I want to select a stock from the picker and it would change the table respectively.

**EDITED**

Controller

```
def index
@stocks = Stock.all.order(:ticker_number)
@stock = @stocks.first
end

def get_stock_market_price
  @stock = Stock.where(id: params[:stock_id]).first
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#stock').change(function() {
      var url_path;
      url_path = "/get_stock_market_price"; // Please replace this url with your original action path.
      return $.ajax({
        url: url_path,
        data: "stock_id=" + this.value,
        success: function(result) {}
      });
    });
  });
</script> 

  <p>
    <%= select_tag "Stocks", options_from_collection_for_select(@stocks, "id", "ticker"), id: 'stock' %>
  </p>

      <div id="marketdata">
        <%= render partial: "market_prices", object: @stock %>
      </div>
```

_market_prices.html.erb

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Market Price</th>           
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @stock.market_prices.order(:closing_date).reverse.each do |mp|%>
    <tr> 
      <td><%=mp.closing_date %></td>
      <td><%=number_with_precision(mp.closing_price, precision: 2) %></td>
    <%end%>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

get_stock_market_price.js.erb

```
$("#marketdata").html('#{ escape_javascript(render partial: "market_prices", object: @stock ) }');
```

routes.rb

```
get "/get_stock_market_price" => "market_prices#get_stock_market_price"
```

Comment: You can add Ajax function on select onChange even using jquery.

Comment: @AmitSharma not sure how it works. Can you elaborate on your answer?

Comment: I have posted my answer please check if it help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= select_tag "Stocks", options_from_collection_for_select(@stocks, "id", "ticker"), :onchange => "update_table(this.value)" %>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function update_table(stock_id) {  
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: "/update_table",
    type: "GET",
    data: {"id" : id},
    dataType: "html",
    success: function(data) {
      jQuery("#tablesDiv").html(data);
    }
  });
}
```

**Controller**

```
def update_table
  @stocks = Stock.where(id => params[:id]).all
  render :partial => "update_table", :object => @stocks
end
```

**Views**
_update_table.html.erb

```
<table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Market Price</th>           
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
<% @stock.market_prices.order(:closing_date).reverse.each do |mp|%>
        <tr> 
          <td><%=mp.closing_date %></td>
          <td><%=number_with_precision(mp.closing_price, precision: 2) %></td>
</tr>

    <%end%>
     </tbody>
         </table>
```

index.htmlerb

```
    <div id = "tablesDiv"></div>
```

Also add a route for /update_table in your routes.rb

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following.

**index.html.erb**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#stock').change(function() {
      var url_path;
      url_path = "/get_stock_market_price"; // Please replace this url with your original action path.
      return $.ajax({
        url: url_path,
        data: "stock_id=" + this.value,
        success: function(result) {}
      });
    });
  });
</script>

<p>
  <%= select_tag "Stocks", options_from_collection_for_select(@stocks, "id", "ticker"), id: 'stock' %>
</p>

<div id="marketdata">
  # Assuming you have stock object in @stock, if not then change following @stock with @stocks.first
  <%= render partial: "market_prices", object: @stock %>
</div>
```

**_market_prices.html.erb**

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Market Price</th>           
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @stock.market_prices.order(:closing_date).reverse.each do |mp|%>
    <tr> 
      <td><%=mp.closing_date %></td>
      <td><%=number_with_precision(mp.closing_price, precision: 2) %></td>
    <%end%>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**stocks_controller.rb**

```
def get_stock_market_price
  @stock = Stock.where(id: params[:stock_id]).first
end
```

**get_stock_market_price.js.erb**

```
$("#marketdata").html('#{ escape_javascript(render partial: "market_prices", object: @stock ) }');
```

**Routes.rb**

```
get "/get_stock_market_price" => "stocks#get_stock_market_price"
```

Comment: It throws that it doesn't find view. And when I change to @stocks.first in index.html.erb view, it breaks down.

Comment: have you added `get_stock_market_price.js.erb` view in app/views/stocks folder ?

Comment: wasn't, but now it renders "#{ escape_javascript(render partial: "market_prices", object: @stock ) }" but not the table

Comment: Can you please post your code what you have done, i think you have missed something

Comment: Posted. I hope you can help.

Comment: seen your edit </tr> is missing in `_market_prices.html.erb` partial.
please can you tell what exactly happening

Comment: Right now nothing is happening. In logs I see 
Parameters: {"stock_id"=>"10"}                                                                                                                                                       
  Stock Load (77.5ms)  SELECT "stocks".* FROM "stocks" WHERE "stocks"."id" = 10 ORDER BY "stocks"."id" ASC LIMIT 1                                                                     
  MarketPrice Load (314.1ms)  SELECT "market_prices".* FROM "market_prices" WHERE "market_prices"."stock_id" = $1 ORDER BY "market_prices"."closing_date" ASC  [["stock_id", 10]]

Comment: why is it still loading stock_id 1 on change? is it referring to @stock still from controller#index?

Comment: Please check your select tag values which is rendering as html on page.